# jQuery on Click not resetting variable for ajax call time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that takes the current time from javascript, sends it as a var to the PHP file, and PHP returns JSON object to JS with anything posted between page load time and now.  (Think SO or Twitter...31 new posts.  Click to load.)

The Ajax call fires every 10 seconds at the moment, and initial check works fine.  But it seems like it doesn't set to the correct time when I click load, as it will still show the same new post available on the next call.  It stops after 2 or 3 calls for some reason.

I'm wondering if I'm either not setting the variable scope correctly, or if I'm missing something glaring.

```
//this time var works fine
lastchecked = new Date();
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    setInterval(function() 
    {   
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php?page=getposts',
            data: { lastchecked : lastchecked },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) 
            {
                var obj = data.length;
                if (obj > 0) 
                {
                    $('#messages').html('<div class="alert alert-info"><a href="#" id="newPosts">' + obj + ' new posts.  Click to load.</a></div>');
                    $('#newPosts').click(function() 
                    {                       
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) 
                        {       
                            if(typeof item == 'object') 
                            {
                                $('#posts').append('<div class="user"> <a href="#" class="clearfix"> <img src="'+item.thumbnail+'" class="thumbnail"> <h4>'+item.post_time+'</h4></a></div>');                  
                            }
                        });

                        $('#messages').empty(); 
                        //this time var doesn't get reset until 2 or 3 calls later
                        lastchecked = new Date();
                        alert(lastchecked);
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

My PHP if needed:

```
$lastchecked = strtotime($lastchecked);
$lastchecked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastchecked);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_time > :lastchecked ORDER BY post_time DESC"); 
$sth->execute(array(':lastchecked' => $lastchecked));
```

Comment: Don't use an interval, overlapping requests will make a mess of your variables. Instead set a timeout in the success callback of the ajax call.

Comment: In the live environment I plan on doing an interval of around 30-45 seconds.  Would that clean it up or would you still recommend `setTimeout` on the function inside the success callback (if I understood correctly)?

Comment: I would always go for a timeout instead of an interval, you never know for sure how long the request will take, on a mobile phone (or anywhere...) the connection might be interrupted, causing problems on your page. By the way, I would also use event delegation to bind the event (the click function) only once and not again and again in the ajax success callback.

Comment: The problem is that now you have one monster function. You should split it up so that you have logical (small...) components, making your program easier to manage and debug.

Comment: set var lastchecked = new Date(); on top